# WebLogic Upgrade Causes JDBC DataSource to fail

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-2012, weblogic12c

My company uses a commercial web tool that we host on-site.  It uses a Java backend and runs out of WebLogic. We recently did an upgrade to the tool and part of it was an upgrade from WebLogic 12.1.1 to 12.1.3.  After the upgrade we noticed that we started getting consistent errors when it tried to do certain things.

From WebLogic's log file:

> java.sql.SqlException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Object has been closed.

The database is SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition (SP3) and running on a Windows Server 2012 box. It appears to only happen when the tool does a SELECT statement against a synonym to another SQL box. If I make that synonym point to something locally, it works. I have verified that Enable XA Transactions is still enabled (as it was before the upgrade).

Sadly, I am unable to turn to the company of the tool since our use of synonyms is not supported with there system. Nothing changed with the database server - what could the issue be?

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. And to be honest, I think you should fight this out with the supplier of your software.